# Convergence of series in functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,...)\in l^{4}, x\neq0$. For which one of the following values of $p$, the series $\sum x_{i}y_{i}$ converges for every $y=(y_{1},y_{2}....)\in l^{p}$.

$A. 1$

$B. 2$

$C. 3$

$D. 4$

It is given that $\sum x_{i}^{4}$ is convergent so $x_{i}\rightarrow 0$ . Let$\sum |y_{i}|$ is also convergent then $y_{i}\rightarrow 0$ . Now I am trying to prove $\sum x_{i}y_{i} $ is convergent . Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Holder's inequality? Also, do you know the relationship between $\ell^r$ and $\ell^q$ if $1\leq r<q < \infty$?

Comment: I am not good in functional analysis...

Comment: Relation between $l^{r}$ and $l^{q}$ is of containment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $1 \le r < q < \infty$, then $\ell^r \subset \ell^q$.

To see this, note that if $x \in \ell^r$, then for all large $i$, we have $|x_i| < 1$, so $|x_i|^r \ge |x_i|^q$. Thus convergence of $\sum_i |x_i|^r$ implies convergence of $\sum_i |x_i|^q$.

---

Hölder's inequality implies $\sum_i |x_i y_i| \le \left(\sum_i x_i^4\right)^{1/4} \left(\sum_i y_i^{4/3}\right)^{3/4}$. If $y \in \ell^1$, then by the above inclusion, $y \in \ell^{4/3}$ as well, which shows $\sum_i |x_i y_i|<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for urs precise time....